# Reputation not getting added

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki, up-votes

My answer was upvoted twice, but I got rep only once, which is has amused me the most!

[image]

Before answering, please do note that I've gone through quite a few posts where there were different reasons given for the Rep not getting added for answer which was upvoted!

1. Reached max. limit of 200. But I guess its no more applicable, as I've gained 240 rep in a day earlier.
2. Made the answer Community wiki. But that's not the case for my answer as my answer was not marked Community wiki. Here's a snapshot for that too.

[image]

As its seen, I edited the answer to check if it was marked CW, but it wasn't. This has totally puzzled me. May be I'm unaware of some new rule which was introduced by SO. Please enlighten me on that.

P.S:- Just as I finished typing my question, my answer got accepted and I got the 15 Rep for that. But it was upvoted again which leaves me with the 10 Rep for the first upvote and 15 rep for the accept. The 20 rep for the other 2 upvotes are missing!

Comment: You just hit the [daily reputation cap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237). Congratulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the reputation cap for the day. It's still +200 rep - the 240 you saw probably involves accepted answers or bounties. Quoting the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/164454) answer:

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested
> edits in any given day. ***Accepted answers and bounties are counted
> separately ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)).*** Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not
> awarded on following days.